# Age of the universe due to expansion

Tags: cosmology, gravity, astrophysics, space-expansion, galaxies

"If gravity working on matter is the only force at work on large scales, then the attactive force of gravity will act to slow the expansion. In this case, the universe was expanding more rapidly in the past than it is now, and the universe is somewhat younger than Hubble time." --- Pg. 16 (Introduction to Cosmology by Barbara Ryden 2nd edition)

Can someone please explain me that if gravity decreases the relative velocity between the galaxies, then how the time is less. Shouldn't it be more and the universe be older than Hubble time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the rate at which the universe is expanding now, that is an observable number $H_0$. We would therefore like to ask: "for a given composition of the universe, what expansion history is required to account for $H_0$?" If gravity is the only force at play, then for it to have decreased the expansion rate to $H_0$ by the present day, the universe must have been expanding faster in the past, meaning it took less time to reach its current size than if the expansion had always been $H_0$ (i.e. the Hubble time).

Answer (score 0):

You look at the universe and you see that everything is flying apart. You measure the velocity and distance. You assume constant velocity and calculate how long ago this started from $t = d/v$.

But if $v$ was higher in the past, you find $t$ is smaller.